# Change object on button down precisely at an object

Tags: unity-game-engine, collision, unityscript

I have a target object (cube), and a fake mouse that I created from an object (sphere) to be controlled by gamepad joystick. I want to bring out another object (let say; sphere), when I push the gamepad button and precisely hit the target object (cube).
Before, I have tried with a mouse click, and it succeeds, but when I controlled the fake mouse with a joystick, when I press the button even outside the target (cube) it still brings out another object. Here is the code, if anybody can help me to revise it. Thanks

```js
function Start () {}
function Update () {

  if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1"))
  {
    var Cube = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Cube");
    if (Cube[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled){
      var Circle1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Circle1");
      Circle1[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled = true;
      Circle1[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).material.color = color.red;
      }
    } 
  }
```

Comment: Where do you check if you clicked on cube or not ? What i see is you just get when button is clicked you do your "thing".

Comment: All you've done is ask "is the user clicking? Ok good. Does the cube *have a mesh*?" (hint: yes it does) "Ok good, spawn the sphere!" You never perform any sort of collision detection.

Answer (score 0):

[solved]
Thanks to EmreE and Draco18s for replying my question. I have solved it, I made a collision trigger indeed.
Here is my code after several trials.

```
if (Input.GetButtonDown ("Fire1") && isCollide)
{

var Cube = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Cube");
if (Cube[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled){
    var Circle1 = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag ("Circle1");
    Circle1[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).enabled = true;
    Circle1[0].GetComponent(MeshRenderer).material.color = Color.red;

Debug.Log("Muncul");
    }
}

function OnTriggerEnter (col : Collider)
{
Debug.Log(isCollide);
if(col.gameObject.name == "Mouse3DSphere")
{
    isCollide = true;
 }
}
function OnTriggerExit (col : Collider)
{
Debug.Log(isCollide);
if(col.gameObject.name == "Mouse3DSphere")
{
    isCollide = false;
}
}
```